# smoothScrollBy bad position

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView`. You can scroll `vertically` and `horizontally` too.
Like this:
[image]

Check the item's `width`.

```
holder.itemView.post(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {

        int cellWidth = holder.itemView.getWidth();

    }
});
```

The width is *5234*.

When I want to `scroll` to the `center`.(I didn't calculate with device's screen's size, but this is not important now.) I call this:

```
recyclerView.smoothScrollBy((5234/2), 0)
```

It is work good on these emulators:

1. 480x800 mdpi (API 24)
2. 480x800 hdpi (API 24)

Isn't work good:

1. 1080x1920 420dpi (API 21)

In 1080x1920. I the recycler width is 5234, when I call the `smoothScrollBy` with 5234/2 . Than It just go to ~1000. So can't jump to center.

Why? :/ The `smoothScrollBy` is waiting PX.

**UPDATE:**

If I use Handler with postDelay, then it works well. So maybe the scrolling is called soo fast. I trying to find better solution.

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){

               @Override
               public void run() {
                   recyclerView.smoothScrollBy(5234/2, 0);
               }
           } ,1000);
```

Comment: add this two lines where ever you set your recyclerview and let me know,  recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true); ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recyclerView, false);

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = this.getViewTreeObserver();
viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        recyclerView.smoothScrollBy(5234/2, 0);
    }
});
```